How do I highlight a specific range within the active row
I have a worksheet with columns A through X, and a variable amount of rows depending on the current project load. During the scheduling meeting, I need to be able to highlight certain rows that need action on them. I have several buttons attached to macros for highlighting single cells, but how do I highlight the current row, through column X?
I know I can just highlight the entire row, but when I resort everything according to the updated due dates, I have yellow bars to the right of the worksheet that don't fit anything anymore.

You didn’t think it was important to include what  software you’re asking about?

This looks like it's about Excel and VBA macros...

Sorry everyone. I feel like crap today and am running a small fever, but still get the pleasure of working. Yes, this is Excel VBA I'm asking about. I was too worried about making sure what I was asking made sense. Still not convinced of that, though.

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("A:X").Interior.Color = .... Depending on what you mean by "current row," you might have a different approach than ActiveCell.

Thanks BigBen, but I get a run-time error saying application-defined or object-defined error. When I click debug, it highlights that row.

Try: ActiveCell.EntireRow.Columns("A:X").Interior.Color = ... but I think it's better to use conditional formatting.

That did it, MGonet. Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
